# When are two groups isomorphic, if we have injective maps between them?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and $\alpha:G\rightarrow H, \beta:H\rightarrow G$ be two maps between them.

Under what conditions can we say that $G\cong H$? Note that we do not require for $\alpha$ or $\beta$ to be an isomorphism. Just for there to exist one.

i) For example, is it true if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are surjective?

ii) It is clearly not true if they are injective. But assume they are both injective. What else do we need for $G$ and $H$ to be isomorphic?

I realise that this is a mathematically badly worded question, as it has obvious answers (such as if they are additionally surjective, haha). But I hope that the question can still be understood. More "categorical" properties are more desirable, but I am generally interested in all of them.

Thanks all in advance.

(Note, groups are not assumed to be abelian).

EDIT: Maybe this is a better way to formulate. What property can I demand on a morphism between groups, that is NOT an isomorphism, BUT if I have such morphisms on both sides, together, they become an isomorphism.

An example as I said, is surjectivity.

Comment: There are injective maps between the free group on $2$ letters and the free group on infinitely many letters.

Comment: I know that this is true for 2 and 3 letters. Not sure if its true for infinity... esp if it is uncountable? But anyway. As I said, injectivity is not enough. I know that. But what else can we say? For example, (and I am just shooting in the blue here), if the orbits of $H$, seen as a $G$-set and vice versa agree. Or something like that. Basically, what else can we say about the maps, without making them isomorphisms separately?

Comment: The obvious answer that $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is surjective might be the only  one in general. The question is too broad right now; perhaps you should restrict $G$ and $H$, say, as free groups of finite rank, or something else. Otherwise it is a bit "shooting in the blue".

Comment: The commutator subgroup of the free group on $2$ letters is free on countably many letters.

Comment: Meanwhile, of course there is no surjection from $F_2$ to $F_\kappa$ for uncountable $\kappa$ *(let alone an injection the other way - assuming choice these are equivalent, but if we don't assume choice they are not in general)* for cardinality reasons alone.

Comment: It is not enough to assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both surjective, even if the groups are finitely generated.

Comment: @Derek Holt aha... I thought it was. But that too brings us to the question of what more one can assume, that would not imply isomorphism for one morphism alone. But, that would imply an isomorphism if it existed both ways... Anyways, its not meant to be a huge question. Just thought that if anyone knew it, it could be useful for something I am trying to do. I am not very strong in group theory, so maybe it was a known thing there...